# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined while using spotify's api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to link the spotify's API to my app, but when i try to run the code, the following error appears :

[image]

here's the code:
First, i use  the `useEffect` to put the script tag and link the API, then, i declare the var `Spotify`, but when the page loads it didn't find the property `Player` in `Spotify`

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

function SpotifyPlayer() {
  
    var Spotify:any

    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
      
        script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
        script.async = true;
      
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      
        return () => {
          document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
      }, []);

      (window as any).onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {

        const token = '[token]';
        const player = new Spotify.Player({
          name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
          getOAuthToken: (cb:any) => { cb(token); }
        });
      
        // Error handling
        player.addListener('initialization_error', ({message}:any ) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('authentication_error', ({ message }:any) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('account_error', ({ message }:any) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('playback_error', ({ message }:any) => { console.error(message); });
      
        // Playback status updates
        player.addListener('player_state_changed', (state:any) => { console.log(state); });
      
        // Ready
        player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }:any) => {
          console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);
        });
      
        // Not Ready
        player.addListener('not_ready', ({ device_id }:any) => {
          console.log('Device ID has gone offline', device_id);
        });
      
        // Connect to the player!
        player.connect();
      };
      
      return <h1>Spotify Player</h1>
}

export default SpotifyPlayer
```

-> I'm using React too.

Answer (score 0):

Your typing for Spotify `any` doesn't have any properties. ;)
Best bet would check if Spotify has a type library and use it here. Otherwise you can use a type with the properties you pointing to.

```
type SpotifyType {
  properties: any; // better to look for the typing config
}

var Spotify:SpotifyType
```

Another option is to try `!` Nonnull assertion

```
const player = new Spotify!.Player({
      name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
      getOAuthToken: (cb:any) => { cb(token); }
    });
```